# How to differentiate this improper integral?

Tags: integration, derivatives, random-variables, improper-integrals

I have a continuous random variable $X$. What I would want to prove is that its median minimizes the expected absolute risk $$\rho(c)=\int_{\Omega}|X-c|f(x)dx=E[|X-c|]$$ where $\Omega$ is the support of $X$ and $f$ its density.

The risk can be expressed like this:
$$\rho(c) = \int_{x \in \Omega \land \geq c}(x-c)f(x)dx + \int_{x \in \Omega \land x < c}(c-x)f(x)dx$$

If $\Omega=[\alpha, \beta]$ with $\alpha, \beta \in R$, I can proceed as follows:
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{d\rho(c)}{dc}=\frac{d}{dc}\int_{c}^{\beta}(x-c)f(x)dx + \frac{d}{dc}\int_{\alpha}^{c}(c-x)f(x)dx
\end{eqnarray}
and then differentiate under the sign of integral to get:
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\frac{d}{dc}\int_{c}^{\beta}(x-c)f(x)dx = \int_{c}^{\beta}(-f(x))dx + (\beta-c)\times \frac{d\beta}{dc} - (c-c)f(c)\frac{dc}{dc} = -\int_{c}^{\beta}f(x)dx  \\
&&\frac{d}{dc}\int_{\alpha}^{c}(c-x)f(x)dx = \int_{\alpha}^{c}f(x)dx
\end{eqnarray}
from where it's straightforward to get:
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\frac{d\rho(c)}{dc} = 0 = -\int_{c}^{\beta}f(x)dx + \int_{\alpha}^{c}f(x)dx \\
&&-1 + F(c) + F(c) = 0 \\
&&F(c) = 0.5 \\
\end{eqnarray}
So if $c$ is a median, then the risk is minimized (because it is a convex function).

However, if $\Omega=(\infty, \infty)$, I'm not sure what to do with:
$$\frac{d}{dc}\int_{c}^{\infty}(x-c)f(x)dx$$
and
$$\frac{d}{dc}\int_{\infty}^{c}(c-x)f(x)dx$$

Differentiating the former w.r.t $c$ gives the following expression:
$$(\infty-x)\frac{d\infty}{dc}=\lim_{y\rightarrow \infty}(y-x)\frac{d y}{dc}$$

Since $y$ does not depend on $c$, it can be treated as a constant , so $\frac{dy}{dc}=0$, but how to show that the whole limit is $0$ (because in that case, the proof is analogous to that for finite $\alpha$ and $\beta$)? $(y-c)\frac{dy}{dc}$ is of the indeterminate form $\infty\times 0$ as $y \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: presumably it is $(-\infty,\infty)$

Comment: Yes, the question is about the case with the infinite support and how to correctly deal with the integrals.

Comment: $0 = \frac{d}{dc}\int_c^{\infty}(x-c)f(x)dx+\frac{d}{dc}\int_{\infty}^c (c-x)f(x)dx = -\int_c^{\infty}f(x)dx+\int_{-\infty}^c f(x)dx$

Comment: yes the limits $\infty$ and $-\infty$ don't depend on $c$ so they differentiate to zero wrt c

Comment: Thanks, @GeorgeDewhirst, I wanted to check that.

Comment: makes logical sense, right?

Comment: It does, but now, I'm not sure how to prove it rigorously. Take a look at this, please. Applying Leibniz's formula we get: $$(\infty-x)\frac{d\infty}{dc}=\lim_{y\rightarrow \infty}(y-c)\frac{dy}{dc}$$ which is the indeterminate form $\infty\times 0$. The limit is equal to $\lim_{y\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\frac{dy}{dc}}{\frac{1}{y-c}}$, but how to get $0$ from there?

Comment: $\frac{dy}{dc} = 0$ for $y>c$

Comment: It is, but the function whose limit we want to take multiplies the derivative with $(y-c)$, so we get $\infty \times 0$ as $y \rightarrow \infty$, which is an indeterminate form.

Comment: well no because $(y-c)\frac{dy}{dc} = 0$ for $y>c$, so it cannot have any limit other than zero

Comment: Yes, if the function is zero everythere, then $0$ is its limit, which is the case here, so I see that. But the form $\infty \times 0$  of $(y-c)\frac{dy}{dc}$ confuses me a bit. :/ Following L'Hospital's rules, I should get that it's zero as well, but I'm stuck.

Comment: well I guess you could write $(y-c)/\frac{dc}{dy}$ and apply L'hopitals on it, to get $1/\infty = 0$

Comment: Thank you, @GeorgeDewhirst . :)